# meteor.js - CollectionFS image categories

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-helper, collectionfs

I’m trying to add an image collection with categories (e.g. Featured Image, Food, Floorplan). I’m using the below code to create an image collection:

```
//create fs collection with gridfs to hold images
Images = new FS.Collection('Images', {
    stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS('Images')],
        filter:{
            allow: {
                contentTypes: ['image/*']
            },
            onInvalid: function(message){
                FlashMessage.sendError(message);
            }
        }
});

//set image permissions
Images.allow({
    insert: function(){
        return: true;
    },
    update: function(){
        return: true;
    },
    download: function(){
        return: true;
    }
});

//create imageinfo collection to hold info about images
ImageInfo = new Mongo.Collection('imageinfo')
```

---

I would like to add categories which allow me to separate the images in front end, and to have a single featured image (can be uploaded specifically for this purpose, does not need to be reassigned from other images).

From what I understand, I have several options for adding image categories:

1. Use the ImageInfo collection to hold info about each image, including the category it belongs to. Not sure how the single featured image would work in this case.
2. Use a more complex file reference system, as suggested in [collectionFS documentation](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#storing-fsfile-references-in-your-objects). I'm not sure how this would be better than the method above.
3. Create a separate FS Collection for each image category, and deal with them one by one.

What would you do in this case?

Comment: Simplest approach is to add the attributes you need to the Images documents themselves! Then everything will come with the images and you won't need to join or keep two collections synchronized.

Comment: I didn't realize I could pass other attributes to the Image. This solved all my problems, thank you!